# Postgres SQL - Split string at Deliminator and replace with substring

Tags: sql, postgresql

My goal is to take the ad_name strings and (1) split sting at the '-' deliminator and then replace that substring with the correct term with a space. so "peelpads" turns into "peel pads", "gtox" turns into "g tox", "meljeans" turns into "mel jeans", and "alexisskirt" turns into "alexis skirt."

```
CREATE TABLE facebook_campaigns
(campaign varchar(255),
ad_name varchar(255),
Media_spend numeric(38,6),
day date);

INSERT INTO facebook_campaigns VALUES
('Peel Pads','retargeting-peelpads-201907', 1000),
('Peel Pads','prospecting-peelpads-201907', 3000),
('Peel Pads','prospecting-peelpads-201906', 2000),
('G Tox','prospecting-gtox-201907', 1000),
('G Tox','retargeting-gtox-201907', 1000),
('Pre Fall','prospecting-meljeans-201907', 1000),
('Pre Fall','retargeting-meljeans-201907', 500),
('Pre Fall','retargeting-alexisskirt-201907', 1500),
('Pre Fall','prospecting-alexisskirt-201907', 2000);
```

I'm able to separate the column by the deliminator but I'm unsure how to isolate that and add the space in the term.  This is what I have done so far.

```
SELECT 
    ad_name,
    regexp_replace('retargeting-peelpads-201907',
                   'peelpads', 'peel pads'),
    SPLIT_PART(ad_name, '-', 2) as product
FROM facebook_campaigns
```

and my result is

```
retargeting-peelpads-201907 | retargeting-peel pads-201907  | peelpads
prospecting-peelpads-201907 |   retargeting-peel pads-201907| peelpads
```

I really just want a column that results to

```
peel pads
```

I just want a column that says "peel pads" because in the end my goal is to combine that column with the "product_name" column in the table below.

```
CREATE TABLE order_line_items
(order_line_item_id bigint,
order_id bigint,
product_name varchar(255),
business_unit varchar(255),
source varchar(255));
​

INSERT INTO order_line_items VALUES
(1, 1,'peel pads','Bananadrinks','facebook'),
(2, 2,'peel pads','Bananadrinks','organic'),
(3, 2,'mel jeans','Redsticks','organic'),
(4, 2,'g tox','Bananadrinks','facebook'),
(5, 3,'alexis skirt','Redsticks','email'),
(6, 4,'alexis skirt','Redsticks','facebook'),
(7, 5,'g tox','Bananadrinks','facebook'),
(8, 5,'mel jeans','Redsticks','facebook'),
(9, 6,'mel jeans','Redsticks','email');
Text to DDL
```

Comment: How do you know what the correct term is?  And I'm confused.  The first column seems to have what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know I want the term in the middle with the space in between. I want something similar to the third column except instead of "peelpads" I want it to say "peel pads". The next step for me after this is to use that term to connect to another table that is why I need the terms isolated

Comment: How do you know (from the input) where the space should be added?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This table will eventually connect to another table with a 'product name' label which is that second term in the ad_name substring but with a space.

Comment: @lydol: you should show this other table and explain your purpose. Presumably, you could remove spaces in values coming from the other table and then join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obvious match on column `facebook_campaigns(campaign)`, but I assumed this is not what you expect.

To join both tables, it looks like it would be sufficient to remove the spaces from the `order_line_items` table, surround the value with hyphens (`-`), and then do pattern matching against column `ad_name` in `facebook_campaigns`:

```
select ...
from facebook_campaigns fc
inner join order_line_items oli
    on fc.ad_name like '%-' || replace(oli.product_name, ' ', '') || '-%'
```